# Parsing error when deploying Tomcat6 JSF application - digester.Digester

Tags: parsing, jsf, tomcat, myfaces, apache-commons-digester

I'm getting a strange parsing issue when I try to start Tomcat6 with my application (that I am trying to port from Tomcat7 to Tomcat6). The Digester itself does not declare an error until it hits an unexpected end of file - this parsing itself must be wrong.

Does anyone have any ideas?

My web.xml is below, followed by part of the console.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<description>ilearn web.xml</description>
    <display-name>iLearn</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>                        javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL </param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
            <param-value>100m</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadThresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>100k</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadRepositoryPath</param-name>
            <param-value>/iLearnData/temp/</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
</web-app>
```

This is the faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <!-- Config here -->
</faces-config>
```

This is the beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

This is part of the log from the console

```
[methodName=setComponentFamily, paramCount=0, paramTypes={java.lang.String}]
2012-09-04 02:20:42,503 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (CallMethodRule.java:615)     - [CallMethodRule]{faces-config/render-kit/renderer/component-family} Call org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.elements.Renderer.setComponentFamily(javax.faces.SelectMany/java.lang.String)
2012-09-04 02:20:42,503 DEBUG [main] Digester.sax      (Digester.java:1094)     - characters(
        )
2012-09-04 02:20:42,503 DEBUG [main] Digester.sax      (Digester.java:1410)     - startElement(http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee,renderer-type,renderer-type)
2012-09-04 02:20:42,503 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1417)     -   Pushing body text '

        '
2012-09-04 02:20:42,503 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1436)     -   New match='faces-config/render-kit/renderer/renderer-type'
2012-09-04 02:20:42,503 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1451)     -   Fire begin() for CallMethodRule[methodName=setRendererType, paramCount=0, paramTypes={java.lang.String}]
2012-09-04 02:20:42,503 DEBUG [main] Digester.sax      (Digester.java:1094)     - characters(javax.faces.Checkbox)
2012-09-04 02:20:42,503 DEBUG [main] Digester.sax      (Digester.java:1164)     - endElement(http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee,renderer-type,renderer-type)
2012-09-04 02:20:42,503 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1167)     -   match='faces-config/render-kit/renderer/renderer-type'
2012-09-04 02:20:42,504 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1168)     -   bodyText='javax.faces.Checkbox'
2012-09-04 02:20:42,504 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1190)     -   Fire body() for CallMethodRule[methodName=setRendererType, paramCount=0, paramTypes={java.lang.String}]
2012-09-04 02:20:42,504 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1210)     -   Popping body text '
  '
2012-09-04 02:20:42,567 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1190)     -   Fire body() for ObjectCreateRule[className=org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.elements.FacesConfig, attributeName=null]
2012-09-04 02:20:42,567 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1190)     -   Fire body() for SetPropertiesRule[]
2012-09-04 02:20:42,568 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1190)     -   Fire body() for SetPropertiesRule[]
2012-09-04 02:20:42,568 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1210)     -   Popping body text ''
2012-09-04 02:20:42,568 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1220)     -   Fire end() for SetPropertiesRule[]
2012-09-04 02:20:42,568 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1220)     -   Fire end() for SetPropertiesRule[]
2012-09-04 02:20:42,568 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1220)     -   Fire end() for ObjectCreateRule[className=org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.elements.FacesConfig, attributeName=null]
2012-09-04 02:20:42,568 DEBUG [main] digester.Digester (ObjectCreateRule.java:219)     - [ObjectCreateRule]{faces-config} Pop org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.elements.FacesConfig
2012-09-04 02:20:42,568 DEBUG [main] Digester.sax      (Digester.java:1254)     - endPrefixMapping()
2012-09-04 02:20:42,568 DEBUG [main] Digester.sax      (Digester.java:1254)     - endPrefixMapping(xsi)
2012-09-04 02:20:42,568 DEBUG [main] Digester.sax      (Digester.java:1114)     - endDocument()
Sep 4, 2012 2:20:42 AM org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider getWebAppFacesConfig
INFO: Reading config /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
2012-09-04 02:20:42,571 DEBUG [main] Digester.sax      (Digester.java:1341)     - setDocumentLocator(com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$LocatorProxy@154e4e31)
2012-09-04 02:20:42,572 DEBUG [main] Digester.sax      (Digester.java:1375)     - startDocument()
2012-09-04 02:20:42,574 ERROR [main] digester.Digester (Digester.java:1655)     - Parse Fatal Error at line 3 column 1: Premature end of file.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1427)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1056)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1745)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.getFacesConfig(DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.java:309)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.getFacesConfig(DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.java:36)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getWebAppFacesConfig(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:345)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.getFacesConfigData(DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.java:75)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:416)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:338)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:140)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Sep 4, 2012 2:20:42 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer initFaces
SEVERE: An error occured while initializing MyFaces: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
javax.faces.FacesException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getWebAppFacesConfig(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:357)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.getFacesConfigData(DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.java:75)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:416)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:338)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:140)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1745)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.getFacesConfig(DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.java:309)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.getFacesConfig(DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.java:36)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getWebAppFacesConfig(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:345)
    ... 21 more
Sep 4, 2012 2:20:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:286)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:206)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Sep 4, 2012 2:20:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /ilearn threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:286)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:206)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Sep 4, 2012 2:20:42 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 4, 2012 2:20:42 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Sep 4, 2012 2:20:42 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/19  config=null
Sep 4, 2012 2:20:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7062 ms
```

Comment: By the way, the Digester log lines repeat many dozens or perhaps a hundred times- I just put a couple of turns in here to give you the idea.

Comment: you have an extra lie after </web-app> , pl remove it and then try

Comment: No extra line in the file - it was just added here to separate the file from the console logs

Comment: What is the content of faces-config.xml ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use JBoss EL.

Instructions

Download the latest version of Seam 2
Extract lib/jboss-el.jar
Copy it to WEB-INF/lib/jboss-el.jar
In your web.xml set:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't match the question. Perhaps you looked in the wrong browser tab?